# how to custom membership providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, membership

I want use custom Role Provider in website. I have this table in Sql server:

[image: SQL diagram]

and I have this class for custom role provider:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    ...
}
```

please help me for use custom membership in web.config. I use this code:

```xml
<membership defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LoginDB1Entities"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
           applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

but when you login get this error from web.config:

*Provider must implement the class 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider'.*

**I want convert [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers) to asp.net 4**

Answer (score 0):

A role provider and a membership provider are two different things.

You need to implement both of them in your case, because you have a custom user as well.

You would register the RoleProvider like this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="WebConfigRoleProvider"> 
  <providers> 
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Login1.Code.CustomRoleProvider"/> 
  </providers> 
</roleManager>
```